# node http server после перезагрузки помнит код до остановки сервера

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер

Я запускаю node http server, смотрю результат выполнения моего кода(РВМК1), после этого останавливаю сервер. Делаю правки в коде, затем запускаю сервер вновь и он показывает результаты выполнения моего кода до изменений, то есть РВМК1, а не РВМК2. Он покажет свежую версию моего кода только если я перезагружу сервер на новом порте. Почему так? Как это исправить?

Comment: Очевидно, дело в кэшировании. Попробуйте его отключить или отдавать файлы каждый раз со случайной солью: `index.html` -> `index.html?XXXXXX`, где `XXXXXX` - любые случайные символы. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632593/how-to-disable-webpage-caching-in-expressjs-nodejs

Comment: Либо использовать принудительное обновление через `Ctrl+F5`, которое игнорирует кэш.